# Is $\sum (a + x/n)^n$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried to solve this by Cauchy's nth root test applied to
$U_n^{1/n}= a+ x/n$

Then after applying limit it results in $a$.
Does that mean convergence and divergence of this series depends upon $a$.
What if $a=1$?
Should I apply another test?
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: $\displaystyle U_n^{\frac{1}{n}} = a + \frac{x}{n}$ ??

Comment: If $a=1$, then $(a+x/n)^n \to e^x \neq 0$. This is another test. What does that tell you about the series?

Comment: @SakethMalyala  yes!

Comment: @RRL Maybe then this whole thing will depend on "x"..... i am not sure..!!

Comment: The root test is telling you it converges if $a<1$ and diverges if $a>1$. You were on the right track. Now I just showed for any $x$ the series diverges in the inconclusive case $a=1$ by the so-called term test. If the limit of the term is not $0$ then the series cannot converge.

Comment: I’m assuming $a>0$. Is that your understanding of the question?

Comment: @RRL oh.. okay okay... i get it..!! thank you  :)

Comment: @RRL yup  ...!  it is not given in question but i don't know other way..!

Comment: Next time use MathJax.  See my edits.

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $|a|<1$, there is always an $N$ such that

$$\forall n>N:\left|a+\frac xn\right|<1$$

(convergence) and the same holds for $>$ (divergence). This settles the case of $|a|\ne 1$.

For $a=1$, we know that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=e^x$$ and the general term does not vanish.

For $a=-1$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-1+\frac xn\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\left(1-\frac xn\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^ne^x$$ does not exist.